# Point domain to website on server

Tags: dns, ip

My client has server which we developed a new website on. We are trying to point an external domain on another server to this website. Do we just update the A record with the highlighted IP or? See image attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your WHM control just have the option to do it (update DNS records) automaticaly. But, if don't. Try adding at **A** records:

- ns1.gandlp.com > 162.144.250.139
- ns2.gandlp.com > 162.144.250.140

  at your DNS **Zone Editor** control on CPanel

Comment: so update the A record along with the nameserver? Where did 162.144.250.140 come from?

Comment: Always that I needed to do it, the slave IP NameServer (or ns2.yourdomais.com) was sequence of master NS IP.
And my Web Host Manages is Similar to yours.

Comment: So I have two add 2 a records?

Comment: If your problem was solved please consider a Vote for my reputation, thanks!!
:)